# Get web page from a list of ip addresses in a file

Tags: linux, scripting, nmap

I have a list of ip addresses in a file, we can call that file ip.txt
I scanned a subnet using zmap at port 80.  So I have about 100 addresses returned into that file.  Instead of popping each ip into a web browser, how would I programmatically go about having a script go through the file and capturing a web page per active ip into a jpg file and saving it in the local directory. I am more of a network/admin guy than a programmer. So the end result would be a capture of active web pages into a directory.

Comment: this may provide some answers .... google `linux headless web browser screenshot`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this loop (Chromium) :

```
#!/bin/bash

while read ip; do
    # chromium or chromium-browser on some Linux distributions
    chromium --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot "http://$ip"
    mv screenshot.png "${ip}.png"
    convert "${ip}.png" "${ip}.jpg" # require ImageMagick
done < ip_list.txt
```

Or this loop (Firefox) :

```
#!/bin/bash

while read ip; do
    firefox -headless -screenshot "http://$ip"
    mv screenshot.png "${ip}.png"
    convert "${ip}.png" "${ip}.jpg" # require ImageMagick
done < ip_list.txt
```

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. Please see [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)